# How to parse event.original field in filebeat?

Tags: filebeat, elk

I would like to extract additional json fields from **event.original**. The documentation says that the field is not indexed and can be overwritten, but I'm not sure how to do this. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-event.html#field-event-original. The field isn't indexed which means that it isn't searchable.

I thought something like

```
- decode_json_fields:
      fields: [event.original]
      process_array: true
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: false
      add_error_key: true
```

would produce the correct output, but no additional fields were created.